# Proof verification for calculation of MLE

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, proof-verification

An intimate question is asked to $n$ persons, $\vartheta \in [0,1]$ is the probability that this question is answered truthfully. Before the question is asked, each person has to roll a dice twice, if the sum is $5$ or $6$ this person answers with 'yes', if the sum is $8$ or $9$ the person will answer with 'no', otherwise he will answer truthfully.
I want to find the MLE for $\vartheta$.

My attempt:

$\mathbf P(yes)=0.25+0.5\vartheta$, $\mathbf P(no)=0.25+(1-\vartheta)$.

The statistic model is given by $(\{1,\dots,n\}, P(\{1,\dots,n\}), Bernoulli)$.

Therfore the likelihood function is given by 
$L_\vartheta(x)=(0.25+0.5\vartheta)^{\sum X_i}(0.25+0.5(1-\vartheta)^{n-\sum X_i}),$ then $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vartheta} (x)=(0.5\sum X_i)(0.25+0.5\vartheta)^{\sum X_i -1}(0.75-0.5\vartheta)^{n-\sum X_i}+(0.25+0.5\vartheta)^{\sum X_i}(-0.5)(0.75-0.5\vartheta)^{n- \sum X_i -1}(n-\sum X_i),$$ setting this equal to zero, then dividing by $(0.75-0.5\vartheta)^{n- \sum X_i -1}$ and $(0.25+0.5\vartheta)^{\sum X_i -1}$ leads to $\sum X_i=n(0.5\vartheta +0.25)$, i.e. the MLE is given by  $\vartheta=\frac{2\sum X_i}{n}- 0.5$

> Is my setting okay and how can I interpret this result now?

Comment: At least the estimate becomes incorrect when $\sum^n_{k=1}X_k=0$ (estimate becomes negative). To edit this recall that you maximize likelihood over $\theta\in [0,1]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **TL;DR :** see the highlighted ending paragraph of the post.

First of all, there are a couple of typos (that don't affect the result). In the first line of your attempt $\mathbf P(no)=0.25 + \color{magenta}{0.5}(1-\vartheta)$, and then for the likelihood $\displaystyle L_\vartheta(x)=\left( 0.25+0.5\vartheta \right)^{\sum X_i}\,\color{magenta}{\big(}0.25 +0.5(1-\vartheta) \color{magenta}{\big)}^{n-\sum X_i}$, the ending exponent should be outside.

At the same time, in the calculation the log-likelihood is correct and the derivative is correct.

In fact, your resut $\hat{\vartheta}=\frac{2\sum X_i}{n}- 0.5$ is correct, and in general for $$\mathbf P(yes)= a + (1-a-b)\vartheta~, \qquad\mathbf P(no) = b + (1-a-b)(1-\vartheta)$$ the MLE as calculated via the same procedure is, denoting $Y \equiv \sum X_i$,$$\hat{\vartheta}=\dfrac{\frac1n Y - a}{1 - a - b}$$ which reduces to your case at $a=b=1/4$.

It is also true that the log-likelihood is always concave at such $\hat{\vartheta}$, that the second derivative is negative for all $0<a<1$, $0<b<1$, and $0<a+b<1$:$$\frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial \vartheta^2}\Bigg|_{\vartheta=\hat{\vartheta}} = -(1-a-b)^2\frac{nY}{ n - Y} \left( \frac{Y}n\right)^{Y-2}\left( 1 - \frac{Y}n\right)^{n-Y}$$

The only amendment you need is to recall that **WHEN** such zero-derivative $\hat{\vartheta}$ is outside of the domain $\vartheta \in [0,1]$, then the "maximizer" is on the **boundary**, as close to that $\hat{\vartheta}$ as possible.

In your case, the MLE is $\hat{\vartheta} \equiv 0$ for an observation of $Y = \sum X_i < a\cdot n = 0.25 n$. This situation is indeed possible, and that indicates your sample is **not very representative of the population**. It happens relatively often when the sample is not "large enough", but the likelihood (both in the technical sense and in daily language) becomes vanishingly small as $n$ increases.

Similarly, $\sum X_i > (1-b)\cdot n = 0.75n~$ is also possible (via "bad luck"), and the corresponding MLE is $\hat{\vartheta} \equiv 1$.

> In conclusion, your calculation is correct, and your MLE is
>   $$\hat{\vartheta} \equiv \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
> 0 &, & 0 \leq \sum X_i \leq \frac{n}4 \\
> \frac{ 2 \sum X_i}n -\frac12 &, & \frac{n}4 < \sum X_i < \frac{3n}4 \\
> 1 &, & \frac{3n}4 \leq \sum X_i \leq n
> \end{array}\right.$$

Note that $\hat{\vartheta}$ is continuous (in $\sum X_i$) at the critical points $n/4$ and $3n/4$.